# succ not getting removed on pred

Tags: list, haskell, prolog, replicate, successor-arithmetics

```
/* Define a Prolog predicate replicate/3 which corresponds to
 * the Haskell function of the same name, except that the numeric
 * argument is expressed symbolically.
 *
 * For example, replicate(s(s(s(0))),a,[a,a,a]) should be satisfied.
 */
```

So far I've come to this solution:

```
replicate(0,_,[]).
replicate(X,Y,[Y|Z]) :- replicate(p(X),Y,Z).
```

but the problem is that the s(s(s(0))) is not getting reduced by the pred function. it results into p(p(p(s(s(s(0))))))

could you guys help me out?

Comment: Prolog doesn't evaluate like that. Try `replicate(s(X), Y, [Y|Z]) :- replicate(X, Y, Z).` instead.

Comment: Oh alright that worked out! Thanks a lot @DanielLyons

Comment: No problem. :) Just pay attention to Prolog, it's evaluation scheme is *very* different than other languages like Haskell. :)

Comment: @Will: Is the [tag:haskell] tag really appropriate?

Comment: @false the OP referred to the Haskell library function, as a reference.

Comment: @Will: Indeed, but why would anyone who searches tag [tag:haskell], want to find this question.

Comment: @false that's how I understand tagging: to reflect what's in the question.

Comment: They are rather here to make things discoverable.

Comment: @false we have five slots to fill. I pick the five most pertinent things about the question and use them as tags. Haskell here seems to be the least pertinent, but still pertinent. I don't have anything to replace it with.

Comment: @Will: We do not have to fill them all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178687/discussion-between-will-ness-and-false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Haskell's `replicate` coded with the (deprecated) `n+k` patterns:

```
replicate 0 _ = []
replicate (n+1) a = a : x where x = replicate n a
```

This directly corresponds to the Prolog definition:

```
replicate(0, _, []).
replicate(s(N), A, [A | X]) :- replicate(N, A, X).
```

We just move the result into the arguments list, and make it the last argument to the predicate:

```
    x = replicate n a    ----->     replicate(N, A, X).
```

The pattern matching is the same. What's not the same, is that Prolog is not an expression-oriented language. There are no expressions which get evaluated before being used as arguments in the next *function* *call*; instead, there are terms which are auto-quoted, always, used *as is* as arguments to *predicates*.

Comment: ... and what's further not the same, is that `replicate(N, s(0), [A,B])` determines `N` *and* `A` and `B`.